# PHP: using => operator without an array

Tags: php

Is there a way to use the PHP `=>` operator (?) without using the `array()` "constructor"?

To be specific, I want to create a function that will get a list of keys and values without wrapping it into an array:

```
function keysAndValues($items) {
    /* ... */
}

keysAndValues(
    'key1' => 'value1',
    'key2' => 'value2',
    'key3' => 'value3'
);
```

Instead of

```
keysAndValues(array(
    'key1' => 'value1',
    'key2' => 'value2',
    'key3' => 'value3'
));
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I know you already accepted an answer, but I took a stab at a pseudo solution.

Comment: It will only work for strings, I wished for a more versatile solution.

Comment: A list of key value pairs *is* in fact an array, (at least in PHP) so what would be the problem with wrapping them in an array?  
I mean, if the PHP interpreter would implement the syntax you propose, it most likely would implement it as an ordinary array just saving you from actually typing `array()` anyway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These would be named arguments. Nope, not possible in PHP. You will have to wrap an array() around them.

If it's not the array that's bothering you but the fact that you have to work with an array inside the function, try

```
function my_function($array)
{
extract($array);
...
if (isset($number)) echo "Number is: ".$number;
}
```

to unpack the options into the function's scope:

```
my_function(array("number" => "one")); // Will output "Number is: one"
```

it saves the hassle of unpacking them one by one using `foreach().`

Comment: Named arguments! that's the one. That got me into this bug report http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=22216 which says PHP development team declined it. Thank you.

Comment: 'If it's not the array that's bothering you' - actually it is, because my goal is a type of dictionary class. I was wondering if there's a better way to send variables to the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing you can get to what you want is by using dynamic arguments.

Using [this tutorial/overview](http://oreilly.com/pub/a/php/2001/05/17/php_foundations.html) as a base, here is a hack to provide a potential solution:

```
function keysAndValues() {
   for($i = 0 ; $i < func_num_args(); $i++) {
       list($key, $value) = explode('=>', func_get_arg($i));
       // Do something with the $key and $value
   }
}
```

It would then be called like this:

```
keysAndValues('key1=>value1','key2=>value2','key3=>value3');
keysAndValues('key1=>value1');
```

Basically, you can have any amount of parameters... they are dynamic!

Comment: Wow, that's hacky. The biggest problem with this is that you'll only be able to pass strings, which can't even contain `'=>'`. It would be better (and less code) to just use arrays here. Nice hack though. :oP

Comment: Haha.. sure is :) However, he listed all his keys as strings... so as long as they don't contain `=>`

Answer (score 0):

well, specifically, the '=>' operator denotes the key, value pair inside an array, so there's really **no reason** to use it outside the array constructor.

that said, it is used inside things like a 'foreach' loop to grab the key and value for each item in an array

```
foreach ($arr as $key=>$val)
```